# button:after not hoverable in Firefox only

Tags: css, firefox

I found a somewhat annoying glitch in Firefox. See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zMX75/2/.

The blue part is supposed to be hoverable. But, in Firefox with a button tag, it simply does not work.

Here is the code:

```
button, .button {
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;display:inline-block;
    height:23px;padding:0 5px;border:0;margin-left:20px;
    font-size: 12px;line-height:23px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000;
    background: #ff0;
    &::before, &::after {
        position:absolute;top:0;
        display:inline-block;width:20px;height:23px;
        content: "";
        background: #00f;
    }
    &::before {left:-20px;}
    &::after {right:-20px;}}
```

I use this code to make an arrow like button using a sprite.

So, I'd like to know if there is a workaround other than changing the tag, because it is used to submit a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to give the button some left and right padding, and to position its `::before` and `::after` over the padding; so that they are inside the button's clickable area.

In other words, adding this to the CSS works:

```css
button {padding:0 25px; margin-left:0;
    &::before {left:0}
    &::after {right:0}
}
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/zMX75/3/).

That said, I'm not sure why it *does* work with the `<a>`. If the button needs to be solved like this, why doesn't the `<a>` need to be treated the same way? Oh well.

Comment: I could use padding, but then I would need to set background-clip to content-box to prevent the background from overlapping to the sides (In my sprite, the sides have to be transparent). Unfortunately, I need to support IE8, so I'm back to square one.

Comment: So the button proper needs to have a background colour (in the fiddle, yellow) but the sides (which are blue in the fiddle) need to be transparent? Hm. I don't think you can do that without changing the HTML. One way would be to put a `span` in the button that contains the text and is yellow. Then you can leave the button itself transparent.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the most workable solution right now, thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Give
    display:block;
Not 
    display:inline-block;